# Javascript: What javascript editor should i use?

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

I am developing a javascript application. Rite now i am using E text editor
http://www.e-texteditor.com

I have used UltraEdit also but i found E-text editor better.
I want to know if there is any other editor more powerful than E-text editor?
and what better facilities it has?

Comment: i like webstorm for js. but its not a free ide.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72106/what-can-i-use-as-a-notepad-alternative-in-linux-ubuntu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What editor should you use? Vim of course! I mean Emacs!

I mean, seriously. There is nothing more personal for a programmer than a choice of his editor. Not even the choice of his language is more personal so I doubt you'll get any meaningful answers other than "You should use *my* favorite editor! Because it's the best." "No, you should use *mine*! Because it's better."

Unless you just want to see a flame war then, well, have fun.

Comment: thats so true. me and my colleague usually have argument for switching to my eclipse or his netbeans, which is fun :)

Comment: I've been writing js in netbeans quite a lot, lately. Has a lot of nice features, and integrates well with php projects. framework comment highlighting is great.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll really find an editor specifically geared towards js, I think you've found what I would choose if you are stuck on a windows platform ;)

I personally use TextMate which is what E-texteditor is modeled after, and if you can harness the specific bundles for any given language you can have some real productivity increases.  You can find framework specific bundles also that include snippets, shortcuts, etc...

But the thing I like about editors like these, there isn't ***so much*** automation that you loose touch with the language.  At its core it's still a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Well i also was looking for a better Javascript editor for some time. However I finally ended up with [**Aptana**](http://www.aptana.com/) since i noticed that is pretty much supportive with Javascript developments.

Obviously it's not an editor but an IDE which is a derivative of eclipse. The thing is that there are lots of libraries and frameworks for Javascript so we can't expect that our editor or IDE is supported with all these.